# Is there a limited number of stardrops in the game?

Tags: stardew-valley

According to the [wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Stardrop) there are several stardrops in the game, most of which seem to be one-off. But two of the requirements are repeatable:

> Giving your spouse a present on their birthday and gifting the Sweet Gem Berry.

Can you only get all of the listed stardrops once? Or can you get those once a year or more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a finite number, in fact, getting them all is an achievement. They cannot be repeated

They can be found:

- at the Stardew Valley Fair for 2000 tokens
- on floor 100 of The Mines.
- by getting your spouse to "13"/12 hearts
- bought from Krobus for 20000g in the Sewers.
- give the statue in the secret woods a Sweet Gem Berry
- getting the Master Angler Achievement

There are two Stardrops that are contested:

Some users swear up and down that there is an additional Stardrops for giving your spouse a birthday present, while others insist that's just the 13/12 one. (I personally got the affection one, then gave Haley a coconut oh her birthday two years in a row and did not receive an additional Stardrop)

Supposedly completing the museum collection awards a Stardrop, but it's possible to get 12/13 honors without completing the museum, with the missing one being "get all the achievements." "Get all Stardrops" is also an honor, so if there IS one from the museum, it doesn't count towards the score at the end.